# Ethereum based settlement engine

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, tokens

What do you meant by settlement engine in ethereum? I need a payment settlement engine that to be based on ethereum for cryptos and security tokens.
Is the same as escrow ?
Any open source link for reference to analyze . Is the openbazaar works on the same concept.